# Thunderbird: How to empty the from field by default when writing mail?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I use some different accounts in Thunderbird and switch a lot between them.

Sometimes I find myself reading mail from one account and suddenly thinking of sending an email not related to what I am reading at all. The new email I want to send is then not necessarily related to the account I was just reading mail from.

By default the "from address" will be the actually selected account email address. If I just quickly write this new email and press the send button without paying enough attention I sometimes send mail from the wrong email address.

Is there are a workaround to provide this from field empty by default so that I am forced to consciously **choose** the "from address" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the *Thunderbird* add-on, *NoComposeAccount* "Have the option of Thunderbird always using the default sender account or a blank account when composing or replying to messages."

There are similar add-ons that associate an account with a color, etc.

*Caveat:* I've not tested these myself, so please report back if one works for you.

Comment: This add-on works perfectly, does exactly what it says (+ some options)

Comment: @Matt, thank you for the useful feedback.

Comment: too bad, the add-on is not yet compatible with thunderbird 74+ :(

Answer (score 0):

For Thunderbird 115.6.0 the addon [Identity Chooser](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/identity-chooser/) works for me.

> **About this Add-on**
> Do you remember the first time you accidentally sent a work related email from your private email account? Identity Chooser helps you to prevent that. It makes choosing the sender address explicit:
>
> • Do you want to compose a new email? Identity Chooser forces you to choose the sender address first.
>
> • Do you want to forward an email? Identity Chooser forces you to choose the sender address first.
>
> To make it short: Every time you'll create a new message, Identity Chooser shows you a menu with all your identities.
>
> Everything in Identity Chooser is about making explicit choices. No automatisms, no defaults.
>
> And as a result you'll never send an email from the wrong email address again.